# PyPE ansi or unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, editor, text-editor, ansi

I want to start programming in python and I read on the internet that PyPE is a good editor. When I went to the website There is the option to download an ansi or unicode version.

Witch one should I use?

Comment: It depends. Do you plan to write code for international use? I generally recommend Unicode from the start; it makes working on the project later a lot easier.

Comment: I don't think this influences the Python code you write. The "ANSI" version might be using 8-bit strings in Windows API calls. Building separate Unicode and ANSI versions was common when the non-Unicode Windows versions (95, 98, ME) still had a significant market share. Since all modern Windows versions are based on Unicode, a non-Unicode build makes little sense, but maybe the PyPE developer decided it wouldn't hurt either. In any case, go for the Unicode version if that works (it also seems to be by far more popular than the ANSI version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend the Unicode version, you can always write your code in plain ANSI, but the features of Unicode are there if you need them.